# How to insert username and password in login window through command prompt

Tags: web-applications, command-line

I have a confusion that can we pass username and password in login form in any website through command prompt such as gmail.com. If we can then how or if not why? Please suggest.

Comment: What is being asked here?  The phrase "command prompt" is used in the Windows world to mean "command line interface" or "terminal" application to non-Windows users. But you also mentioned "such as gmail.com" which uses a GUI.  If you mean a GUI then you should say "dialog box" or "input form" or "textfield".  Which do you want to know about, CLI or GUI?

Comment: I just want to ask you about CLI that works outside the windows like passing username and password to gmail. how can I pass both values through command line interface. I have confused that how can it possible with knowing textbox id. is this possible or not.

Answer (score 0):

The way to access websites from the command line (CLI, terminal, command prompt, etc.) is to use tools like `curl` and `wget` which exist on any Unix type box.  Equivalents such as putty exist for Windows.

If your username was "Alice" and your password was "asdf" you can access password-protected web pages like so:

```
curl -u Alice:asdf --silent http:/example.com/blahblahblah
```

The way to get your gmail from the command line can be found here: http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/3380/check-your-unread-gmail-from-the-command-line.  It isn't too hard to adapt this code to what you need.

Be aware though that since you are using the commandline and not a browser you aren't really logging into to a multi-page application; you are just hitting one HTTP resource using your credentials.  Perhaps that's all you need.

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>curl -u username:password --silent https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=fals
e&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F%3Fui%3Dhtml%26zy%3Dl&bsv=llya6
94le36z&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&from=login
'curl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
I wrote this command on command prompt and it gives the above error. Please explain me where i m wrong. I passed my gmail username and password in this command.